# <img> sizes attribute doesn't work while loading

Tags: html, css

I am using HTMLImageElement.sizes to define the width of my image.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/sizes

```css
img {
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<img srcset="https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-sm.jpg 120w,
            https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh.jpg 193w,
             https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-lg.jpg 278w"
     sizes="(max-width: 710px) 120px,
            (max-width: 991px) 193px,
            278px">
```

Although the size is set correctly depending on the viewport width the image size works only once the image stars to is fully loaded.

You can see that the image is only 0x0px during load in this video:

[image]

I am looking for a dry way which doesn’t require to define and maintain the size once in html and once in css as this is harder to keep in sync. Also the `sizes` attribute is required for performance reasons: [Why can’t we just do this using css or javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#why_cant_we_just_do_this_using_css_or_javascript)

Is there any trick to use the sizes already before the image has been downloaded?

Comment: maybe with min-width: nPX;

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, you need:

1. Add css breakpoints with **@media**.
2. Set the initial height.
3. Set **aspect-ratio** as the original image.

The *aspect-ratio* only works (in this case) if it has width or height, without both of those properties *aspect-ratio* doesn't work.

```css
img {
  --initial-height: 360px;
  height: var(--initial-height);
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 278/360; /* original image size - width / height */
  object-fit: contain;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  img {
    --initial-height: 193px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 710px) {
  img {
    --initial-height: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img srcset="
        https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-sm.jpg 120w,
        https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh.jpg    193w,
        https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-lg.jpg 278w
      " sizes="(max-width: 710px) 120px,
            (max-width: 991px) 193px,
            278px" />
```

Comment: but this would require duplicating and double maintaining every size and always keep css and html in sync - isn't there a more dry way which makes use of the width given in sizes?

Comment: We need to define initial width, height in html or css. If we put tags height, width in html, then we will lose the **sizes**. Another approach, create a preloader, but for this we need again initial width and height. The article on [web.dev](https://web.dev/codelab-specifying-multiple-slot-widths) used the same method with **@media** as mine.
As a compromise, you can remove **sizes** from img tag and only use css.

Comment: Without sizes the srcset attribute does not work 
So I was hoping for a solution which doesn't require setting the size in css a second time as keeping both in sync is error prone

Comment: @jantimon the srcset attribute on img works without specifying sizes also, please refer this mdn page - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset

Comment: @Ddmteetu but that’s only for pixel density srcSets - correct?

Comment: @jantimon yes the example that is there on the mdn page, using srcSets for pixel density but you can try to use it with width descriptors, like this "header640.png 640w, header960.png 960w, header1024.png 1024w, header.png", this is also listed there on the page and I think it'll work for your case as well the sizes then can be put with in CSS, how I tried using it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do a trick to render a block (a div) of a size that fits the aspect ratio of your image and then the image can be placed with a position set to absolute with respect to the block, the block will be relative. This way your image will always be sized with respect to the div and only thing that you're doing by keeping the sizes attribute with the img tag itself that you can do but for the holding block, I mean the div. You can set width for different view-ports for that div and then the image will automatically be scaled with the div.

The only condition for this to work is that the aspect ratio of your images, that you're using in the srcset of img, should be equal. Because right now what I can see is that all the 3 images have different aspect ratio, this you'll need to make equal because then only the images will have width and height scaling proportionately on different view-ports.

**For eg**: lets say your image is of size **120px X 155px** (I'm using your smallest image for explaining the thing, **aspect-ratio for this is 24:31**), then the holding block (the div) will have width set for different view-ports, the same way you're setting it for your img using the sizes attribute. And then the height can be calculated by giving a bottom-padding of 129.2%.

You can say, css will be as below:

```css
div.holder-element {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 129.2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
}
.top-holder-to-keep-the-layout-okay, .holder-element {
  width: 280px;
}

@media (max-width: 740px) {
  .top-holder-to-keep-the-layout-okay, .holder-element {
    width: 120px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1192px) {
  .top-holder-to-keep-the-layout-okay, .holder-element {
    width: 193px;
  }
}

div.holder-element img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-holder-to-keep-the-layout-okay">
  <div class="holder-element">
    <img srcset="
          https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-sm.jpg 120w,
          https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh.jpg 193w,
          https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-lg.jpg 278w
        " />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Please remember to keep aspect ratio same for all of your images on different view-ports.

With this solution your images will scale properly with the holding div, and div with orange background will anyways be shown even if the image inside it is not loaded.

I hope this will give you some idea to proceed further.

Comment: This requires to keep sizes and css in sync which is painfull to maintain..

Comment: Why do you want to keep the sizes attribute with your img tag, you can keep the sizes added to the holder div with media breakpoints and then your image will automatically be scaled with respect to the holder div, as the image will be absolutely positioned to the div, the div will have the width and the height will be assigned to it based on the width proportionately.

Comment: here is an explanation why you should not use CSS without sizes for performance reasons: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#why_cant_we_just_do_this_using_css_or_javascript

Comment: understood that images are loaded first by the browser and then the JS and CSS, so to let browser decide which image size to load it's necessary to use sizes with srcset.

Comment: @jantimon then why don't you just create a holder div and nest your img with in that. This way you can use a min-width: 120px (width of your smallest image) and a min-height: 155px (height of your smallest image) and then when the actual image will be loaded the container/holder div will be resized to contain the image and on initial load when the image will be loading, you will see that block, as you'll have min-width and min-height given to it. This assignment you can do on the div tag itself and since that will be the parent of your image so, it will get rendered first with the added style.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the sizes of the images according to the div container of your image.
And in addition to the comments above you can use `picture` element rather than the `img`. You can use multiple `source` elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
</picture>
```

Comment: cool idea with picture - unfortunately `picture` should only be used for art direction and would not allow reusing larger images from cache 

Answer (score 0):

@jantimon If you'll keep your img tag with all the attributes that you have, in a holder div as shown below, then your problem with keeping the size while image is loading will be resolved:

```css
.holder-element {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 120px;
  min-height: 155px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: orange;
}
.holder-element img {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder-element">
    <img srcset="https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-sm.jpg 120w,
            https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh.jpg 193w,
             https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-lg.jpg 278w"
          sizes="(max-width: 710px) 120px,
            (max-width: 991px) 193px,
            278px">
</div>
```

**Note:** give this solution a try, I hope this will work for you

Comment: this still requires to keep the size once in css and once in html..

and for larger screens it would lead to layout shifts as the image grows in size during load

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="holder-element">
   <img srcset="https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-sm.jpg 120w,
        https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh.jpg 193w,
         https://www.dofactory.com/img/html/vangogh-lg.jpg 278w"

     sizes="(max-width: 740px) 120px,
        (max-width: 991px) 193px,
        278px">
</div>
```

**Style**

```
.holder-element {
  width: 120px;
  height: 360px;
}

.holder-element img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 360px;
  aspect-ratio: 3/4;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@media (min-width: 740px) {
  .holder-element {
     width: 193px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1192px) {
   .holder-element {
      width: 278px;
   }
 }
```